# How to know when binding has updated on dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am creating a custom control with a dependency property that I want to bind a custom class to. When the property gets update I want to call a method so that it can reconfigure the control... I am lost.

```
 internal partial class CollectionScheduleDayView : Canvas
    {
        public static DependencyProperty AppointmentsCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Collection", typeof( AppointmentCollections ), typeof( CollectionScheduleDayView ), new PropertyMetadata( null, PropertyChangedCallback ) );


        private static void PropertyChangedCallback( DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            SetDataContext( dependencyObject, e );
        }

        public AppointmentCollections Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValue( AppointmentsCollectionProperty ) as AppointmentCollections;
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue( AppointmentsCollectionProperty, value );
            }
        }

        public CollectionScheduleDayView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void CollectionScheduleDayView_DataContextChanged( object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {

        }


        private static void SetDataContext( DependencyObject control, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
        {
            var dayView = control as CollectionScheduleDayView;

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                if (dayView != null)
                {
                   dayView.Collection = e.NewValue as AppointmentCollections;
                   dayView.DataContext = dayView.Collection;
                   dayView.SetupControl();
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetupControl()
        {
            ResetControl();

            Collection.RescheduledAppointments.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( RescheduledAppointments_CollectionChanged );
            Collection.CompletedAppointments.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( CompletedAppointments_CollectionChanged );
            Collection.RemainingAppointments.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( RemainingAppointments_CollectionChanged );

            if (Collection.RescheduledAppointments == null || Collection.RescheduledAppointments.Count == 0)
            {
                CollapseRescheduled();
            }
            if (Collection.CompletedAppointments == null ||Collection.CompletedAppointments.Count == 0)
            {
                CollapseCompleted();
            }
        }

        //...some other code below 
}
```

I bind to my property just fine:

```
<my:CollectionScheduleDayView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" x:Name="DayView0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Collection="{Binding DayOneAppointmentCollections, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SourceUpdated="CollectionScheduleDayView1_OnSourceUpdated"/>
```

The `PropertyChangedCallback` only gets called once and never calls the method again to update the control; however, the binding is getting updated and when the source gets updated the property gets updated...also onpropertychanged() does not get called in my viewmodel.

When I force onpropertychanged() to be called in my viewmodel by re-instantiating the object that is bound to my control - the binding works once but it does not update when the property changes even though onpropertychanged() is being called.

How am I supposed to know when the binding is updated? Is my dependencyproperty code correct?

Comment: Note, that your PropertyChangedCallback is for the AppointmentsCollectionProperty, which holds a reference to a collection. Ofcourse, changing that property means changing the reference, a-ka assigning another collection object to it. If you do not assign another collection object (or null) to the property, then this property obviously doesn't change... If you want to know about whether something changes inside the collection itself, then you will have to subscribe to the respective events of that collection (ObservableCollection offers such an event).

Comment: in the code above I do this: `Collection.RescheduledAppointments.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( RescheduledAppointments_CollectionChanged );` where `Collection.RescheduledAppointments` is an ObservableCollection - this doesnt work...

Comment: Okay, then be more specific about your problem scenario: Is CollectionChanged not being fired if you add/remove items to the collection objects to which you added that CollectionChanged handler? Or is your issue rather that you don't get to know when (for example) Collection.RescheduledAppointments is set to another ObservableCollection? From your question it is not clear what/where your issue is exactly.

Comment: Its both - I have tried both methods and neither is working

Comment: Both? That are two entirely different topics. For the CollectionChangedHandler: Your problem is that either the handler is being removed again (without you being aware of it -- look in your code), or that particular ObservableCollection object you subscribed to doesn't get items added to/removed from (but rather another ObservableCollection object). The second topic would be regarding changes of AppointmentCollections properties: Implement the *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface for your AppointmentCollections class, and subscribe to its *PropertyChanged* event.

Comment: AppointmentCollections does implement INotifyPropertyChanged...I need to make sure onprorpertychanged is being called on those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things there that look wrong to me.

1  This isn't needed since the binding will do that for you.  If you put a breakpoint here, you should see that dayView.Collection and e.NewValue are already the same.

```
dayView.Collection = e.NewValue as AppointmentCollections;
```

2  This also isn't needed.  I think this is probably the main culprit since you're changing the DataContext to where "DayOneAppointmentCollections" no longer exists.

```
dayView.DataContext = dayView.Collection;
```

3  In SetupControl be sure to unsubscribe from the old collection.

Comment: Based on the acceptance, not setting the DataContext worked for you?

Comment: it was a combination of all three - I think it was more so de-attaching the events. Not setting the data context seems to be easy enough to get around considering you can bind to to the control using relativesource - which I'm still trying to make happen - but that would be a different question...Both you and @elgonzo gave good suggestions

Comment: A trick that I use (instead of using RelativeSource) to do that binding is to name the root of your control and then use ElementName in your binding.

<UserControl ... x:Name="Root">
...
<TextBox Text={Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SomeProperty />
... </UserControl>

Comment: So if the name was like Canvas1 I could do like ElementName=Canvas1.Collection.RemainingAppointments - I will have to look into using that - thanks

Comment: Close.  It would be "{Binding ElementName=Canvas1, Path=Collection.RemainingAppointments}".  If you have something like ReSharper that can do intellisense in XAML, you can see the properties appear once you set the ElementName binding.

Comment: Yea...I saw your edit after adding the comment going to use that now